# Django compressor does not uglify javascript

Tags: django, uglifyjs, django-compressor, terser

I wish to use [Django Compressor](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to both minify and uglify my css and javascript. I have got it working such that I do an offline compression and all required javascript is compressed correctly.

The problem is that it does not uglify the code. My settings:

```py
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
    "compressor.finders.CompressorFinder",
)
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
COMPRESS_YUGLIFY_BINARY = "yuglify"
COMPRESS_YUGLIFY_JS_ARGUMENTS = "--mangle"
```

`yuglify` is on my path. I tried running it manually on a file to test, ie:`yuglify file.js --mangle`. It turns out that `yuglify` (which is a wrapper around [uglify-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js)) does not support `es6` and above.

I found another uglifier called [terser](https://github.com/terser-js/terser) which works perfectly from the terminal with `es6` code. I therefore tried to replace the above settings with terser, ie:

```py
COMPRESS_YUGLIFY_BINARY = "terser"
COMPRESS_YUGLIFY_JS_ARGUMENTS = "--mangle"
```

This also does not work in `django-compressor`. The result is that the files get minified but not uglified.

I would appreciate any suggestions on getting this working either with `django-compressor` or with an alternative package.

Comment: This is a waste of your time. Minified code won't make your page noticeably faster. Ugly code won't stop people from understanding it. Combining many tons of enormous files into one will save you bulky additional requests, but won't be as efficient as not having all that unnecessary weight in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the docs the default setting for COMPRESS_JS_FILTERS is

```py
COMPRESS_JS_FILTERS = ['compressor.filters.jsmin.JSMinFilter']
```

So you need to add the 'compressor.filters.yuglify.YUglifyJSFilter' filter to it.

```py
COMPRESS_JS_FILTERS = [
  'compressor.filters.jsmin.JSMinFilter',
  'compressor.filters.yuglify.YUglifyJSFilter',
]
```